# Как использовать свои программы для работы на сервере SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

В данном примере я использую команду **ls** которая запускаться на сервере *example.com*

```
ssh root@example.com   "ls  /home/admin/web"
```

но как будет выглядеть команда где **ls** будет запускаться с локального ПС  и отработает на сервере *example.com*?

Comment: Что-то я вообще ничего не понял. Команда запускается на сервере example.com. Вы спрашиваете, как запустить команду на сервере example.com. Каким боком тут локальный ПС?

Comment: Если на сервере нету команды ls ? А у меня она есть на локалке и я хочу ее запустить на сервере

Comment: никак. процесс выполняеся тем процессором, на котором и запущен. хотя, возможно, вы так заваулированно пишете про банальное монтирование файловых систем.

Comment: Одно я знаю точно , что с удаленки по ssh я локально запускал приложения которых нету на локалке , и ещё в графическом интерфейсе

Comment: @skatchmast *с удаленки по ssh я локально запускал* - Вы ошибаетесь. Когда Вы вошли по ssh на удалённый сервер, то всё, что Вы делаете, делается ТАМ. Если не верите, попробуйте в окне ssh выполнить команду *ls > result.txt* и посмотрите, где образовался файл *result.txt*. Совершенно аналогично, если Вы выполните команду *ls ~* то у Вас выдасться содержимое Вашего домашнего каталога ТАМ, а не из локального хоста.

Естественно, Вы МОЖЕТЕ запустить приложение, которое есть ТАМ. Вот только выполняться оно будет вовсе не ЗДЕСЬ.

Comment: Запускали вы их удалённо, а не локально. Локально они только отображались.

Comment: В ряде случаев сработает `scp prog user@host:prog; ssh user@host sh -c "chmod +x prog; ./prog"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от поставленных задач, если к примеру нужна работа с файлами, а на удаленный ПК не поставить нужного ПО: то можно монтировать нужные каталоги и обрабатывать их через свою оболочку.

```
sshfs user@example.com:/home/admin/ /mnt/directory
```

и уже после этого можно делать локально `ls /mnt/directory/web/` или какие либо действия с файлами.

Упоминаний о возможности запустить установленный на удаленном сервере пакет лично я не встречал.

*
*Сначала была идея полностью монтировать файловую систему своего ПК и перенести свои переменные окружения с поправкой на точку монтирования, но слишком много неизвестных для меня, возможно кто то поэкспериментировал и поделится опытом)*